# Using and condition in creating a new column in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to compare 2 columns in a pyspark data frame - var_pulled and var_prod and produce a new column as the indicator. If var_pulled is null and var_prod is in ['0','@','~',' '] then I want the new column to be 1 else 0. Following is the code that I am using  -

```
g9_all2 = g9_all1.withColumn('var', when((g9_all1['var_pulled'].isNull() & (g9_all1['var_prod'] in ['0','@','~',' '])) ,1).otherwise(0))
```

Here is the error that I get -

> Cannot convert column into bool: please use '&' for 'and', '|' for
> 'or', '~' for 'not' when building DataFrame boolean expressions.

Can someone please help me? Is there a workaround to & in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made up some sample data to achieve what you are looking for.

```
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F


    spark = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName('so')\
        .getOrCreate()

    sc= spark.sparkContext

    df = sc.parallelize([
        (None, "0"), ("abc", "^"), (None, "~"), ("belgium", "!")
    ]).toDF(["var_pulled","var_prod"])

    df.show()

    # +----------+--------+
    # |var_pulled|var_prod|
    # +----------+--------+
    # |      null|       0|
    # |       abc|       ^|
    # |      null|       ~|
    # |   belgium|       !|
    # +----------+--------+

    df.withColumn("new_col", F.when((F.col("var_pulled").isNull() & F.col("var_prod").isin('0','@','~',' ')), 1).otherwise(0)).show()


    # +----------+--------+-------+
    # |var_pulled|var_prod|new_col|
    # +----------+--------+-------+
    # |      null|       0|      1|
    # |       abc|       ^|      0|
    # |      null|       ~|      1|
    # |   belgium|       !|      0|
    # +----------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your second check to `g9_all1['var_prod'].isin(['0','@','~',' '])`

Comment: It says - TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Could you try changing it to `col('var_prod').isin(['0','@','~',' '])` ?

Comment: I tried - TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable